# Python Regex to find CRLF

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, newline

I'm trying to write a regex that will find any CRLF in python.
I am able to successfully open the file and use newlines to determine what newlines its using CRLF or LF.  My numerous regex attempts have failed

```
with open('test.txt', 'rU') as f:
   text = f.read()
   print repr(f.newlines)
   regex = re.compile(r"[^\r\n]+", re.MULTILINE)
   print(regex.match(text))
```

I've done numerous iterations on the regex and in every case it till either detect \n as \r\n or not work at all.

Comment: You can FIND all the CRs, one at a time, using `text.find('\r')`, no regex required.

Comment: If you want to observe CR and LF, why are you opening the file with universal newlines mode, which will convert line endings?  Also, this is tagged `python-3.x`, yet you're clearly using Python's 2's `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `re` library to search for the `\r` & `\n` patterns.

```py
import re

with open("test.txt", "rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"\r\n", line):
            print("Found CRLF")
            regex = re.compile(r"\r\n")
            line = regex.sub("\n", line)
        if re.search(r"\r", line):
            print("Found CR")
            regex = re.compile(r"\r")
            line = regex.sub("\n", line)
        if re.search(r"\n", line):
            print("Found LF")
            regex = re.compile(r"\n")
            line = regex.sub("\n", line)
        print(line)
```

Assuming your test.txt file looks something like this:

```text
This is a test file
with a line break
at the end of the file.
```

Comment: Nice, you can add another statement for  `\n` because a UNIX-like OS uses `\n` to terminate a line.

Comment: Yes, we could search for LF as well.

Comment: I tried this and regardless of CRLF, CR, or LF, I'm still getting it all registered as LF.

Comment: I got this to work use open("test.txt", newline="").  but trying to search using re.compile and match, is yielding nothing.

Comment: BTW: for your syntax highlighting language indicators, just `txt` or `text` doesn't work to indicate plain text (i.e. no syntax highlighting). That value needs to be a full language specifier (e.g. `lang-text`, `lang-txt` ), a tag (e.g. `python`, `javascript`), or `none`. Please see [answer to: "What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"]([answer to: "What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, you're opening the file with [*universal newlines*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0278/), which means that Python will automatically perform newline *conversion* when reading from or writing to the file.  Your program therefore will not see CR-LF sequences; they will be converted to just LF.

Generally, if you want to portably observe all bytes from a file *unchanged*, then you must open the file in *binary* mode:

In Python 2:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import re

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
   text = f.read()

regex = re.compile(r"[^\r\n]+", re.MULTILINE)
print(regex.match(text))
```

In Python 3:

```py
import re

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
   text = f.read()

regex = re.compile(rb"[^\r\n]+", re.MULTILINE)
print(regex.match(text))
```